# Authorize.net Accept.js payment processor

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, authorize.net

Authorize.net recently released their Accept.js payment processing method -- very similar to Stripe.  The big advantage is that CC data goes directly from the user's browser to Authorize.net's servers.  Never touches your server, greatly reducing PCI scope and compliance challenges.

http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html

Wondering if there are other Authorize.net users who'd be interested in co-sponsoring an Accept.js payment processor for CiviCRM?

For those who might say "just use Stripe" -- with our transaction volume, their fee structure would cost us an extra $20000 / year vs. what we have with our own CC merchant account + Authorize.net.